# TreeView и MSSQL по нескольким таблицам (WinForms, c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server, treeview

Бьюсь уже долгое время, но, увы, хорошего примера и рабочего кода не нашел. Или не понимаю смысл чтения из бд в Treeview) прошу помощи.

Есть 4 таблицы такого вида

[image: Страны]

[image: Регионы]
[image: Города]
[image: Организации]

Нужно вывести по ним Treeview вида **Страны - Регионы - Города - Организации**.
TreeFast (FastTree) не катит - нужны линии отображения нодов. Хотя с FastTree я в итоге построил.

Comment: Это плохая идея вместо структуры таблиц дать ссылки на картинки в интернет. Задавая вопрос нужно ценить чужое время

Comment: Берите любой `TreeView` и вставляйте в него узлы, в чем проблема? Если нужна какая-то базовая функциональность от дерева, то распишите ее подробнее. Структура конкретных таблиц весьма слабо связана с вопросом.

Comment: все-таки нужно начать с нормального запроса к БД...